# Stop a WinForms app from running a second time, and if it does, close the first instance

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a project in WinForms, and I want to make sure it doesn't run twice at the same time. It's a program that works quietly in the background. I've figured out how to detect if someone tries to open it again.

I use this function to detect if the program is running or not:

```
private bool IsAlreadyRuning()
{
    const string appName = "RocketAlert";
    bool createdNew;
    mutex = new Mutex(true, appName, out createdNew);

    if (!createdNew)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, I want it to close the already running program if it detects that it's already running. How can I achieve this?

I've attempted to make adjustments with the 'NamedPipeClientStream', but it appears that its presence in my project is causing issues. The program either doesn't start or it's unable to read files.

Comment: Use a custom Windows message that you can post from the newly started instance to the main window of the already running one. Obviously, you'll need a handler for the message that calls App.Terminate, or something like that. (Most people do it the other way around - stopping the new instance when one is already active - because the active one may have data that needs to be saved, and so on).

Comment: Why not end the current instance if another is already running (instead of ending the other one) ?

Comment: Simply kill all processes of the same name that their process id is not the same as you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.onstartupnextinstance?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Do you want to close the first one opened or the most recent one?

Comment: I want to Kill the "old" run becouse it will be more easy method for "restarting" the program like this.
The second option is to close the "new" run, what is easy, but how do I "restart" the old one for my need.
The end resuld needs to be: one instance is runing and runing from the begining like it's been restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To satisfy the first clause of your question **Stop a WinForms app from running a second time**, one conventional approach that detects a reentrant instance of the app is by setting a [Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-7.0).

Subsequent attempts to invoke the static entry point `static void Main()` will be unable to enter the mutex block. If the goal is to prevent the new instance from running, take this opportunity to leave the running instance alone and prevent new one from running, per my original answer.

---

To satisfy the second clause of the question **if it does, close the first instance**, we can take a different approach. using the *original no mutex* version of `Program.cs`,  make the the main form class broadcast a WM_USER message after taking care to innoculate itself from the effects. Other window instances of MainForm will now close themselves.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    SemaphoreSlim sslimNotMe = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        Text = "Creation Time " +  DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss tt");
        if (!PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SWAP_FOR_NEW_INSTANCE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to post message");
        }
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SWAP_FOR_NEW_INSTANCE)
        {
            try
            {
                if (sslimNotMe.Wait(0))
                {
                    Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                sslimNotMe.Release();
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public static int WM_SWAP_FOR_NEW_INSTANCE { get; } = RegisterWindowMessage("{FC0A54D8-F999-493A-B8D1-DF4E8FCF08E4}");

    #region Dll Imports
    private const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF;
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

    #endregion Dll Imports
}
```

---

Previous answer, using `Mutex` to avoid a new instance (per the first part of the question).

```
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if(Mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            try
            {
                ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
                Application.Run(new MainForm());
            }
            finally
            {
                Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm, "The app is already running!");
        }
    }
    static Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(
        true,
        // Use Tools\Create Guid to generate an arbitrary identifier.
        "{FD4DF30D-C22A-499C-A814-EA2A21BDE585}"
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried your code in a test app, and it worked perfectly. However, in my program, it doesn't seem to do anything. The program still runs twice simultaneously, and each one acts like its own separate program.

Comment: I have just hit the 'rebuild solution' and try to run the .exe file that located in the bin/Debug and again, My program started second time and now I have two programs running at the same time

Comment: Sorry my [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/one-hot-app-instance.git) was inadvertently private. DEBUGGING: When I set a break in `WndProc` and start in VS, the `sslimNotMe` is "hit-and-skipped". Next, leaving that one running, now I click the .exe in \bin Debug and see the `sslimNotMe` breakpoint 'hit and entered' in VS, which closes the instance running in VS.

Comment: When I set a break point in the `WndProc` it's not even entering the if statment (no matter if the program is already runing or not).
If you want you can check my program here [link](https://github.com/Kirozen2020/RocketAlert).
Sorry if it's messy. For more detales, I am trying to put your code in the Form1.cs

Comment: Thanks for the repo things are clear now. The reason you see **program still runs twice simultaneously** is that you're unconditionally setting `e.Cancel` in `Form1_FormClosing`.  (Look in TaskManager - still running even after closing window by clicking [X].) Sometimes it makes sense to 'hide-instead-of-close' but you should respond to `e.CloseReason` for example  `protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) { base.OnFormClosing(e); switch (e.CloseReason) { case CloseReason.UserClosing: e.Cancel = false;  break; default:  e.Cancel = true; Hide(); break; } }`

Comment: By extension, this means that if you're closing the form in response to `WM_SWAP_FOR_NEW_INSTANCE` you may have to set a `bool` flag or something to tell the `FormClosing` event that you really _do_ intend to close the window.

Comment: Hi, did it workd in yours runs ?
Maybe I am missing somthing
I am not using the ```Form1_FormClosing``` the Form1 is alredy minimized when the code runs, I tried to add your solutoin and delete the FromClosing event but it's making no diffrent

Comment: I cloned your repo from your link and am using your latest commit which has `private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){  e.Cancel = true;   this.Hide(); }` There's not anything here that uses any of my sample code. And Minimized is not the same as Closed. I know you'll figure this out though. Good luck!